# Add the "selected" attribute to a drop down option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add the attribute "selected" to a drop down menu option based on that option matching some variable?

Here is how the dropdown is populated...

```
loginOptions = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
        var Login = $( '#Login' );

        for ( var i = 0; i < loginOptions.length; i++ ) {
            Login.append('<option value="'+ loginOptions[i] +'">'+             loginOptions[i] +'</option>');
        }
```

I want to mark one option as "selected" based on whether or not its value matches another variable. so if `loginOption[i]` is equal to `var existingLoginValue` then set that option to 'selected'

Something that would do

```
if(loginOptions[i] === existingLoginValue){ print 'selected'; };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) at the end of your method, this sets based on value, like this:

```
$('#Login').val(existingLoginValue);
```

Similarly, to get the value, call it without any parameters like this:

```
var currentValue = $('#Login').val();
```

Comment: That's a great solution. Wish I'd have thought of that rather than wasting time playing around with setting selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do one value then yeah, the `val()` works. Otherwise, you can also do this:

```
$option=$('<option value="'+ loginOptions[i] +'">'+ loginOptions[i]+'</option>').appendTo(Login);
if (loginOptions[i] == existingLoginValue) {
    $option.attr('selected',true)    
}
```

er, someone pointed out this doesn't really make sense since that would imply multiple options with the same value. I meant to write something like this:

```
existingLoginValues = ['foo','bar']
$option=$('<option value="'+ loginOptions[i] +'">'+ loginOptions[i]+'</option>').appendTo(Login);
if (existingLoginValues.indexOf(loginOptions[i]) != -1) {
    $option.attr('selected',true)    
}
```

the `indexOf` function is supported in most browsers except (of course) IE6. See ["Best way to find an item in a JavaScript Array?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: ...When would you have 2 options with the same exact value?  In his code there are 3 distinct options.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#Login').selectedIndex = i
```