# How to add title attribute to Chosen option tags?

Tags: jquery-chosen

I'm using "Chosen plugin" and not sure how to add an attribute to the option tags of the select list.

I have tried this using jQuery on document ready but no luck.

Comment: It's very likely you cannot ... but could you provide a better explanation of where you're talking about?

Comment: this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428212/add-the-selected-attribute-to-a-drop-down-option-with-jquery

Comment: Did you find an option for this? Chosen seems to correctly copy over classNames from the underlying Option objects, but ignores the title attribute.

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell did you still need an answer? I noticed you didn't favourite this question, so you wouldn't've been notified of a new answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to modify the Chosen.Jquery.js to the following to make it work

Using Chosen 1.0 version

Line no 62 add this line of code

```
this.parsed.push({
        array_index: this.parsed.length,
        options_index: this.options_index,
        value: option.value,
        text: option.text,
        html: option.innerHTML,
    title: option.title, // this is Line 62 add this line
        selected: option.selected,
        disabled: group_disabled === true ? group_disabled : option.disabled,
        group_array_index: group_position,
        classes: option.className,
        style: option.style.cssText
      });
```

Modify Line No 255

```
return "<li title=\"" + option.title +"\"  class=\"" + (classes.join(' ')) + "\"" + style + " data-option-array-index=\"" + option.array_index + "\">" + option.search_text + "</li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

`I have tried this..but no luck`

That depends what you tried.
Give this function a go, calling it with the select element that you want its chosen counterpart to inherit titles

```js
function cloneTitles(selectBox) {
    //make sure it has already been chosen-ised
    selectBox = $(selectBox).chosen();

    //get all the original options, should be in same order as chosen ones
    var origOpts = selectBox.find('option');

    //get all the chosen-created 'options'
    //NB there may be a better way to grab the chosen created element
    var chznOpts = selectBox.next().find('.active-result')

    //foreach option
    origOpts.each(function(index, origOpt) {
        //copy the attribute from the original
        $(chznOpts[index]).attr('title', $(origOpt).attr('title'));
    });
}
```

`I have tried this on document ready`
Your problem may have been that you were doing whatever you tried before chosen.js had converted your select boxes, but this function should mitigate that.

Also, if you need this for multiple select boxes, just use `.each()`
(E.g. `selectArray.each(function(i, select) { cloneTitles(select); })`

I assume you're using jQuery and not Prototype (given your last line)
So you could pass in '#id' instead of <DOMObj> if you wanted.
Code could be modified to clone a given attribute, instead of `'title'`, or even an array of given attributes!

Comment: Kind of assumed your select element's options already had title attributes set, given @Nicholas Tolley Cottrell 's comment.

But if not, have no fear, modify the function to accept an array of title strings and use those instead of 'chznOpts'

note this will have to be ran whenever Chosen updates the dropdown, usually only instigated by a `.trigger('liszt:updated')`

so you probably wont need to worry about that

Comment: Hi all, I just wanted to say Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Using Chosen 1.1 version

```
html: option.innerHTML,   // Search
title: option.title,      // Add
```

.

```
option_el.innerHTML = option.search_text;    // Search
option_el.title = option.title;              // Add
```