# Tooltips for each option of Chosen jQuery plugin

Tags: events, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I use [Chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).
How can I show a tooltip when the mouse pointer is on some option?

UPDATED:
Please notice, that my main question is about a tooltip for an OPTION. Not for whole "combobox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution I could come up with was to make chosen respect the `title` attribute on original `<option>` tags because there doesn't seem to be a good way to alter the format of the DOM.

Edit `chosen.jquery.js` (version 1.0.0):

Around line 55: add the `title` to the `this.parsed` array:

```
html: option.innerHTML,
title: option.title,
selected: option.selected,
```

Around line 253: update the returned `<li>` to include a title:

```
return "<li title=\"" + option.title + "\" class=\"" + (classes.join(' ')) + "\"" + style + " data-option-array-index=\"" + option.array_index + "\">" + option.search_text + "</li>";
```

Comment: Looks like I came to the same conclusion as the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569903/how-to-add-title-attribute-to-chosen-option-tags

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this, here's how I did it without modifying chosen:

```
$('#yourid').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function() {
    $('#yourid_chosen .chosen-results li').each(function() {
        var s = this;
        s.title = $(s).text();
    });
});
```

This method uses Chris's idea, but wraps it in the showing_dropdown event.

Comment: Will this be fired every time the dropdown is shown?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `.on('mouseenter')` with li selector, it covers the results case which doesn't happens in the `chose:showing_dripdown` case:

```
$('.select2-results').on('mouseenter','li',function(){$(this).prop('title','A tile')});
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest approach

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Tooltip Combobox Stackoverflow</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("select").each(function() { 
        var s = this; 
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) 
            s.options[i].title = s.options[i].text; 
        if (s.selectedIndex > -1) 
            s.onmousemove = function() { s.title = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text; }; 
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
<select id="combobox">
<option value="">Select one...</option>
<option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
<option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
<option value="Asp">Asp</option>
<option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="C++">C++</option>
<option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
<option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
<option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
<option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
<option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
<option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
<option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
<option value="Java">Java</option>
<option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
<option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
<option value="Perl">Perl</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="Python">Python</option>
<option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
<option value="Scala">Scala</option>
<option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
</select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution just create a tooltip, but my question was about creating tooltip WHEN the mouse pointer is on the one of the item of Chosen "combobox"

Comment: @KurtHolz I think this is what you are asking for. Take a look and accept the answer if it helps, thanks!

Comment: @Chris - The question is regarding a specific plugin replacement for select, not a general select element. Further, this code doesn't work in webkit browsers, such as Safari.