# Does chosen having the ability to add tooltip for a long text Tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .net, jquery-chosen

```
Is there is any possible way to add tool tip on mouse hover of a tag having long text.
```

**For Example**:-
I have a tag with name `EveryThingIsPossibleRightHere` Currently the tag is showing like 
 `EveryTh....` I want to know how can i show the full tag name on mouse hover like a tooltip in Chosen Jquery ?
I had already done with [Tooltips for each option of Chosen jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013844/tooltips-for-each-option-of-chosen-jquery-plugin) but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with problem like you have ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4or7bstp/6/

Comment: It is fully visible like you want as I see.

Comment: check the tag how can i show it as a tool tip on mouse hover

Answer (score 0):

By using title attribute tool tip can be set, like below.

`<option value="1" title='EveryThingIsPossibleRightHere'>EveryThingIsPossibleRightHere</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Way to do it with **chosen**

```
Go to line no 869 of chosen.jquery.js
After "class": "search-choice", Add "title": item.text 
In order to show the tool tip
```

**Final Code will be**

```
choice = $('<li />', {
        "class": "search-choice",
        "title": item.text
      }).html("<span>" + item.html + "</span>");
```

**For View**
Just mouse hover on the tag in order to see the tool tip