# Find by values in JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have such an array:

```
arr['key1'] = true;
arr['key2'] = true;
arr['key3'] = true;
...
arr['keyN'] = true;
```

How to determine, have anyone key a "false" value?

Comment: *Possibly duplicate:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/ (may not work when looking for `true` and `false` though).

Comment: If you have an array you shouldn't be using non-numeric properties on it. If you need non-numeric properties, use a plain object.

Comment: Felix, can you answer, that to i can flag your answer like a decision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this until recently was to loop through the array; if you're using this in a browser-based app, you'll probably have to do it that way. There are new array features in ECMAScript 5th edition (the new JavaScript) that let you do this in a slightly different way, but only some browsers support them (and I'm not sure they'd necessarily be applicable).

But what you've described in your question is more a map (or "dictionary;" sometimes called an *associative array*) than an array (numerically-based indexed thingy). In JavaScript, "array" is usually used to mean numerically-indexed arrays (e.g., created via `[]` or `new Array`), and "object" is usually used for maps (because all JavaScript objects are maps). (This can be a bit confusing, because arrays *are* objects. But don't worry about that.) So this is an array:

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

...whereas this is an object ("map", "dictionary", "associative array"):

```
var o = {key1: 'one', key2: 'two', key3: 'three'};
```

Your use of non-numeric indexes suggests you're really using a map, not an array. The search loop looks something like this on maps:

```
var key, found;

found = false;
for (key in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (!arr[key]) {   // <== There are alternatives, see notes below
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

There I've used `if (!arr[key])` to check for the `false` value. That will actually stop on `false`, `undefined`, `null`, or an empty string. If you really, really want `false`, use `if (arr[key] === false)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(key in arr){
  var value = arr[key];
  if(!value){
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function hasFalse(arr) {
    for (i in arr) {
        if (!arr[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This returns as soon as a single false is found.

Answer (score 0):

There is one jquery method to  find any value in javascript array

$.inArray(false, arr);

It returns -1 if no such matching found

Answer (score -1):

1. loop through each value in the array (for-loop)
2. check the value to see if it's false.

are you new to Javascript?

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === false) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to be sarky, he's probably wondering if there's a built-in array function that will do it for him. Not an unreasonable thing to hope for.

Comment: @TJ, Looping through an array is always a couple of examples away from "Hello World". So no, I'm not being sarcastic.

Comment: Not, i'm not new in JS. But i finding way to not write myself if there is found decision.

Comment: @Anurag: Reads sarcastic to me (and apparently someone else, but just one someone else). *(Edit: Okay, so now it's two other people.)*

Comment: @Ax.. there are some great answers available here. I suggest you start with simple answers, and test all others from there. If you want an online tool to quickly test a piece of Javascript code, then checkout http://www.jsfiddle.com

Comment: @TJ, so what you're saying is that you have three accounts on SO?