# Javascript If statement, looking through an array

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Mind has gone blank this afternoon and can't for the life of me figure out the right way to do this:

```
if(i!="3" && i!="4" && i!="5" && i!="6" && i!="7" && i!="8" && i!="9" && i!="2" && i!="19" && i!="18" && i!="60" && i!="61" && i!="50" && i!="49" && i!="79" && i!="78" && i!="81" && i!="82" && i!="80" && i!="70" && i!="90" && i!="91" && i!="92" && i!="93" && i!="94"){

//do stuff

}
```

All those numbers need to be in an array, then I can check to see if "`i`" is not equal to any 1 of them.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/javascript-array-containsobj

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to find an item in a JavaScript Array ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet, you're right too. I've marked that function as a dupe as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var a = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

if ( a.indexOf( 2 ) == -1 ) { 
   // do stuff
}
```

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the number is not found. It returns something other than `-1` if it is found. Change your logic if you want.

Wrap the numbers in quotes if you need strings ( `a = ['1','2']` ). I don't know what you're dealing with so I made them numbers.

IE and other obscure/older browsers will need the `indexOf` method:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)  
{  
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)  
  {  
    var len = this.length >>> 0;  

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;  
    from = (from < 0)  
         ? Math.ceil(from)  
         : Math.floor(from);  
    if (from < 0)  
      from += len;  

    for (; from < len; from++)  
    {  
      if (from in this &&  
          this[from] === elt)  
        return from;  
    }  
    return -1;  
  };  
}
```

Comment: seeing this just makes me love jQuery even more.

Answer (score 3):

My mind made this solution:

```
function not(dat, arr) { //"not" function
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  if(arr[i] == dat){return false;}
}
return true;
}

var check = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,18,19,49,50,60,61,70,78,79,80,81,82,90,91,92,93,94]; //numbers

if(not(i, check)) {
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: One benefit of using `indexOf` is that it's already built into most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is cross-browser:

```
var valid = true;
var cantbe = [3, 4, 5]; // Fill in all your values
for (var j in cantbe)
    if (typeof cantbe[j] === "number" && i == cantbe[j]){
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
```

`valid` will be `true` if `i` isn't a 'bad' value, `false` otherwise.

Comment: It's very bad practice to use `for...in` on arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't call it bad practice, as long as you know what you're doing. I've added a check: `typeof cantbe[j] === "number"`.

Comment: @SimpleCoder, because `for-in` is meant to *enumerate* object properties, to *iterate* over array objects, a sequential loop is always the best, [more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848).