# How to check whether a given string is already present in an array or list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Javascript - array.contains(obj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/javascript-array-containsobj)
>   [Best way to find an item in a JavaScript Array ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array)

I want to check, for example, for the word "the" in a list or map. Is there is any kind of built in function for this?

Comment: See the linked question for some very good answers.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have "lists" or "maps". It has arrays and objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript you have Arrays (lists) and Objects (maps).

The literal versions of them look like this:

```
var mylist = [1,2,3]; // array
var mymap = { car: 'porche', hp: 300, seats: 2 }; // object
```

if you which to figure out if a value exists in an array, just loop over it:

```
for(var i=0,len=mylist.length;i<len;i++) {
  if(mylist[i] == 2) {
     //2 exists
     break;
   }
}
```

if you which to figure out if a map has a certain key or if it has a key with a  certain value, all you have to do is access it like so:

```
if(mymap.seats !== undefined) {
  //the key 'seats' exists in the object
}

if(mymap.seats == 2) {
  //the key 'seats' exists in the object and has the value 2
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Array.indexOf(element)` returns -1 if element is not found, otherwise returns its index

Comment: The indexOf() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier.