# how to split function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have data in

```
var description="Name:John;EmployeeID:2;Salary:$8000;Address:London";
```

i want the result as

```
Name: John
Employee Id: 2
Salary: $8000
Address: London
```

is it possible with split() function in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this statement:

```
var arrDescription = description.split(";");
```

you will get an array with all the values. For more info on `split` check the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

you can even join them afterwards :

```
printf(arrDescription.join(" "));
```

For more info on `join` check the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Max

Comment: how can i find a substring from arrDescription

Comment: @Saloni: are you trying to find an item in an array ? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/javascript-array-containsobj

Comment: i have only substring not the complete string

Comment: if i understand well, you want to do a search in your array with substring only. you could do a loop on your array but there might be a more efficient way so i advise you to ask another question so that javascript gurus will provide you with the best answers

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) but in this case it's simpler to use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var description="Name:John;EmployeeID:2;Salary:$8000;Address:London";
description = description.replace(/;/g, '\n').replace(/:/g, ': ');
/*
"Name: John
EmployeeID: 2
Salary: $8000
Address: London"
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result as an object, try:

```
var f = function (str) {
    var x = {}, key2label = { EmployeeID: 'Employee Id' };
    str.replace(/(.+?):(.+?)(;|$)/g, function (match, key, value) {
        key = key2label[key] || key;
        x[key] = value;
    });
    return x;
};
```

If a simple string is needed, but you still need to replace keys:

```
var f2 = function (str) {
    var key2label = { EmployeeID: 'Employee Id' };
    return str.replace(/(.+?):(.+?)(;|$)/g, function (match, key, value, semi) {
        key = key2label[key] || key;
        return key + ': ' + value + (semi ? '\n' : '');
    });
};
```

If you really didn't mean to replace keys, this will do it:

```
var f3 = function (str) {
    return str.split(':').join(': ').split(';').join('\n');
};
```

... or use Matt Ball's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can probable try like this to display.

```
       var description="Name:John;EmployeeID:2;Salary:$8000;Address:London";
       var arr=new Array();
       arr=description.split(";"); 
       for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
           document.writeln("<h4>"+arr[i]+"</h4>");
```

Comment: if i have description in textBox then how can i use split function.

Comment: You can get the description from textBox using  document.getElementById("textBoxId").value

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You first should `split` on the semicolon `;`. Loop through those results, and `split` each result on each colon `:`.

You will have to build the result by hand.

Answer (score 0):

var description="Name:John;EmployeeID:2;Salary:$8000;Address:London"; var splitted = description.split(";");

for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) { document.write(splitted[i] + ""); }