# jquery match: how to find whether a keyword exists in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, split, match

How can I find whether a keyword exists in an array which was splitted with split()?

```
// Get the object infomation.
var keyword = 'story';
var path = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
var array_url = path.split('/');

if(keyword == array_url) alert('match!'); // does it work like this??
```

The url path from a tag is something like this - `www.mysite.com/story/article-1`

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
if ($.inArray(keyword, array_url)) alert('match!');
```

this will alert the match whether the array has the keyword in it or not.

Comment: sounds similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `if(keyword == array_url) alert('match!');` // does it work like this??

Well, does it? ;)

jQuery has a [convenience function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) for searching through arrays.

```
if ( $.inArray(keyword, array_url) > -1 ) alert('match!)';
```

Or, in your case, you could use regular JavaScript string operations:

```
if ( $(this).find('a').attr('href').indexOf(keyword) > -1 ) alert('match!)';
```

Comment: thanks. see my edit above. but the regular JavaScript string operations works fine. why not jquery?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: There's nothing wrong with using jQuery. It's just that splitting a string into an array and then searching through the array for what's basically nothing more than a "partial string match" is kinda complicated

Comment: I think this is how to do it in jquery method as Dogbert says, `if ($.inArray(keyword, array_url) != -1) alert('match!');` thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.inArray returns -1 if match is not found.

You should do

```
if ($.inArray(keyword, array_url) != -1) alert('match!');
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

`if ($.inArray(keyword, array_url) > -1) alert('match!');`

Comment: I apologize for the typo. You're right, I always make this mistake.