# how to check whether a particular number is present in JSON array

Tags: jquery, arrays

JSON array is `var ParamArr = [1,2,3,4]`

In the above array I want to check particular number contains in that array

I tried this but not working

```
if (!ParamArr.includes(4)) {
  ParamArr.pop(4);
}
```

Comment: Use `Array.indexOf(<item>)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery match: how to find whether a keyword exists in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456810/jquery-match-how-to-find-whether-a-keyword-exists-in-an-array)

Comment: Please take the time to search for your answer before asking a question. This is one of the most basic operations you can do with an array, which has literally thousands of answers already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function :

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

if(arr.indexOf(4) > -1){
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(4), 1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

If you want to remove the element, the function [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is here for you.

Answer (score 1):

you have it almost correct, but you have a logical issue with your solution. you need to check if array contains the element. so you need to use condition `ParamArr.includes(4)` and not `!ParamArr.includes(4)`

```js
var ParamArr = [1,2,3,4];
if (ParamArr.includes(4)) {
  ParamArr.pop(4);
}

console.log(ParamArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple function like this:

`function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}`

And check with:

`isInArray(4, ParamArr);`

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray) has a utility function for this:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

Returns index of `value` in `array`. Returns `-1` if `array` does not contain `value`.

Also check  [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.inArray demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>"John" found at <span></span></div>
  <div>4 found at <span></span></div>
  <div>"Karl" not found, so <span></span></div>
  <div>"Pete" is in the array, but not at or after index 2, so <span></span></div>

  <script>
    var arr = [4, "Pete", 8, "John"];
    var $spans = $("span");
    $spans.eq(0).text(jQuery.inArray("John", arr));
    $spans.eq(1).text(jQuery.inArray(4, arr));
    $spans.eq(2).text(jQuery.inArray("Karl", arr));
    $spans.eq(3).text(jQuery.inArray("Pete", arr, 2));
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var ParamArr = [1,2,3,4];
if (ParamArr.indexOf(4) >= 0) {
  ParamArr.pop(4);
}

console.log(ParamArr);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

plain old javascript

```
var tempArray = [1,12,13,14,4];
var elemToBeFound=tempArray[4]; //get the last elem in this ex
 if(tempArray.indexOf(elemToBeFound) > -1){ //means it is present in the array
   var indexOfElem=tempArray.indexOf(elemToBeFound);
   // do what you want to do . you have the index in that array
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

var ParamArr=[1,2,3,4];

if( $.inArray(4, ParamArr) !== -1  )

{

```
    //To do
```

}