# How can I store elements into an array, and check to see if a value exists?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, validation

I am creating a form that allows you to sign up for alerts on our website, by allowing a user to input the keywords into a form.

I have setup the validation, although the jquery I have used seems somewhat convoluted even to me, it works!

I am now trying to setup the form so that when you input a keyword, it checks to see if you have already put in that keyword.

e.g. I've added "cloud" to my list, and I accidentally try to add it again, the form should alert me and not allow me to add it to my list.

I think the solution would be to store the keyword in a "KeywordList" array, then cycle through using a for each loop like in PHP:

```
foreach (KeywordList as KeywordListArrayElement){
         if(KwValue == KeywordListArrayElement){
           alert ("The keyword '+KwValue+' has already been added");
           return false;
         }
}
```

But I don't know how to store the Keyword in the array or fetch it from it

here is my html:

```
    <form action="" method="get" name="Test Form" target="_self" id="alerts_form" dir="ltr" lang="en">
        <fieldset id="alerts_options">
            <label for="email_address">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="on" required="required" value="" /><div class="email-alert form_val" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid email address</div><br />
            <label for="keywords">Keyword(s): </label>
            <input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords[]" tabindex="2" autocomplete="on" value="" />
            <button id="addKeyword" name="addKeyword" value="">+</button><br />
            <div id="KeywordList"></div>
            <div class="keyword-alert form_val" style="display: none;">Please input at least one keyword</div>
            <label for="frequency">Frequency: </label>
            <select tabindex="3" id="frequency" name="frequency"><br />
            <optgroup>
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Daily</option>
            <option value="7">Weekly</option>
            <option value="30">Monthly</option>
            </optgroup>
            </select><div class="frequency-alert form_val" style="display: none;">Please make a selection</div><br />
            <input type="hidden" id="Step" name="Step" value="2" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <button class="alert_button" type="submit" id="submit" name="UpdateAlertOption" value="Unconfirmed">Submit</button><br />
            <button class="alert_button" type="submit" name="UpdateAlertOption" value="Delete">Delete</button><br />
            <button class="alert_button" type="submit" name="UpdateAlertOption" value="Delete All">DeleteAll</button>
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="" class="KwdBox" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#addKeyword").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var KwValue = $("#keywords").val();
    if($("#keywords").val()==""){
        alert('Please input a keyword');
        }

        else
        {
            var squareBrackets = "[]";

                $("#keywords").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
                $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").hide();
            $('<input type="text" class="KwdBox" name="keywords'+squareBrackets+'" value="'+KwValue+'" tabindex="2" autocomplete="on" required="required"/>')
            .appendTo('#KeywordList');
            $("#keywords").val("");
            $(".KwdBox").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).remove();

            });
        }
    });

    $("#alerts_options .email-alert").hide();
    $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").hide();
    $("#alerts_options .frequency-alert").hide();

    $("#submit").click(function(){


        var frequency = 1;
        if($("[name=frequency]").val()==""){
        frequency = 0;
        }else{
        frequency = 1;
        }
        var keyword = 1;
        if($("#keywords").val()=="") {
        keyword = 0;
        }
        if($(".KwdBox").val() >""){
        keyword = 1;
        }
        var email = 1;
        if(!checkEmail($("[name=email_address]").val())){
        email = 0;
        }else{
        email = 1;
        }
        //frequency empty, email empty, kw empty
        if(frequency == 0 && email == 0 && keyword == 0){
            $("#keywords").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=email_address]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=frequency]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');        
            $("#alerts_options .form_val").show();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $("#alerts_options .form_val").hide();
        } //frequency empty, email on, kw empty
        if(frequency == 0 && email > 0 && keyword == 0){
            $("#keywords").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=email_address]").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("[name=frequency]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');    
            $("#alerts_options .email-alert").hide();
            $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").show();
            $("#alerts_options .frequency-alert").show();
            return false;
        }//frequency empty, email on, kw on
        if(frequency == 0 && email > 0 && keyword > 0){
            $("#keywords").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("[name=email_address]").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("[name=frequency]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("#alerts_options .email-alert").hide();
            $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").hide();
            $("#alerts_options .frequency-alert").show();
            return false;
        }//frequency on, email on, kw empty
        if(frequency > 0 && email > 0 && keyword == 0){
            $("#keywords").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=email_address]").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("[name=frequency]").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("#alerts_options .email-alert").hide();
            $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").show();
            $("#alerts_options .frequency-alert").hide();
            return false;
        }
        if(frequency > 0 && email == 0 && keyword > 0){
            $("#keywords").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("[name=email_address]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=frequency]").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("#alerts_options .email-alert").show();
            $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").hide();
            $("#alerts_options .frequency-alert").hide();
            return false;
        }
        if(frequency == 0 && email == 0 && keyword > 0){
            $("#keywords").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("[name=email_address]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=frequency]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("#alerts_options .email-alert").show();
            $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").hide();
            $("#alerts_options .frequency-alert").show();
            return false;
        }
            if(frequency > 0 && email == 0 && keyword == 0){
            $("#keywords").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=email_address]").css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 232, 232)');
            $("[name=frequency]").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $("#alerts_options .email-alert").show();
            $("#alerts_options .keyword-alert").show();
            $("#alerts_options .frequency-alert").hide();
            return false;
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's a good thing you don't need to add another input or two to that form, because you would need a whole lot more `if` statements.

Comment: Use indexof

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: I know Chris, it wouldn't be so bad if the whole form didn't contain required fields, if there is a better way to do it please feel free to suggest it, as it can't be good having to process that amount of if statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use an array. Use a map/associative-array instead. You can do something like this:

```
var keywords = {};
```

Then if your keyword is in the variable `keyword`, you can do:

```
keywords[keyword] = true;
```

So if you had the keyword `cloud`, what you basically have is:

```
keywords['cloud'] = true;
```

To check for its existence, all you have to do is:

```
if(keywords[keyword]) {
  ...
}
```

Now to add your keywords to the list, you can do something like this:

```
var KwValue = $("#keywords").val();

var keywordArray = KwValue.split(/\s*,\s*/); //assuming that your keywords are separated by commas:

for(var i = 0; i < keywordArray.length; i++) {
    var keyword = keywordArray[i];

    if(!keywords[keyword]) {
       keywords[keyword] = true;
       ...
    }
}
```

This is O(n), but it is better than the O(n<sup>2</sup>) you would get with an array.

Comment: Thanks Vivin, I initially made the schoolboy error of putting `var keywords = {}` within the .click() function, resulting in it being cleared every time! Thankfully realised it and didn't take too long to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method, and least expensive is to use an array (which you are), but put the keywords into the array as the array's key's:

```
var keywords = {}; // not really an array, but we'll just pretend it is

keywords['hello'] = true;
keywords['there'] = true;
etc...
```

After that, checking for a keyword's existence is a simple matter of

```
if (keywords[yourvarhere]) {
  ... it exists
}
```

which saves you the whole overhead of searching the array each time you need to check for a particular keyword.