# jQuery: check input value against values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm attempting to check the values entered by a user into an input text field.  Once they enter the value and click submit, if the value they enter matches a value in an array, I'm attempting to produce one result, if not in the array, another result.

Basically have a simple form like so:

```
<form id="checkinput" action="#">
<input type="text" value="" id="couponcode" name="coupon code name"/>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When click "#submit", if value in the "#couponcode" input field equals the value in an array, add a class of "success" to a div with an id of "success_show" otherwise a simple alert like "your coupon code is wrong" would be displayed.

I'll have a hidden div and upon success, add a class of "success" to the div.

The array will change periodically and will have different quantities at different times.  Something simple like so:

```
var arr = [ "CA238", "Pete", 8, "John" ];
```

Comment: out of curiosity can I see a live demo of this site if you have it up and running?

Comment: I wouldn't keep those arrays in the JS I'd use AJAX to check either against a database or a PHP array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use jquery...

```
$.inArray(value, array) // returns -1 if value doesn't exist, otherwise returns index
```

**EDIT**
If you don't use jQuery then you can use indexOf on the array

```
if(array.indexOf(value) < 0){ // doesn't exist
    // do something
}
else { // does exist
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function include(arr, obj) {

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === obj) return true;
    }
}

var arr = [ "CA238", "Pete", 8, "John" ];

$("#submit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

    var val=$("#couponcode").val();
    if(include(arr, val))
        alert("success");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kCYkx/5/

hel taken from [Best way to find if an item is in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array)

OR

use [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

    var val=$("#couponcode").val();
    if($.inArray(arr,val))
        alert("success");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kCYkx/6/

Answer (score 0):

You could use -

```
function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
```

Taken from this question - [Best way to find if an item is in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

well your array needs to be created like this:

```
var a=[];
a["couponcode"]="CA238";
a["name"]="peter";
```

or a json as follows:

```
var a={ couponCode:"CA238", name: "peter"}
```

with that in place now when you want to validate your form run it through all the inout element be using say `$.each` and then get the id of each of the input and get the vlaue of the same from the array that you have created or from the json compare the two values and see if it is correct.

code will be like:

```
$("input").each( function()
{

    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    if(a[id])   // for json a.hasOwnProperty(id)
    {
      if($(this).val()!==a[id])
      {
        // do the necessary
      }

}
});
```