# What's the best way to dynamically add or remove objects from container in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have an array of strings, `['12', '34', '56']`, and I want to dynamically update this array by adding additional elements (`'78', '90'`), or by removing some elements (`'34', '56'`).

Not sure if there's a better data structure/library that gets the job done. Can someone shed some lights for a JS newbie?

Comment: Related to adding array elements: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2010/10/javascript-array-performance/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: Go to any Javascript resource and look up the Array object and study the methods there. You can't learn Javascript by asking a question here every time you want to know how to add one and two. Learn how to learn from all the resources out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to an array use [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
var arr = ['12', '34', '56'];
arr.push('78', '90');
```

Removing a specific element, may take a bit more work.  To to that, you'll need to copy the array into a new one (without the element(s) you want to remove).

John Resig (creator of jQuery) posted a function to remove array elements by their indexes (which you'll need to get 1st).  His function is [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/).

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
var arr = ['12', '34', '56'];
arr.remove(arr.indexOf('34'));
arr.remove(arr.indexOf('56'));
```

Update: [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) could also work to remove elements.

```
var arr = ['12', '34', '56'];
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('34'), 1);
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('56'), 1);
```

Note: [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) may not work in all browsers.  There is a function that will add it to older browsers at the [MDN docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can usually do anything with the provided arrays and objects.

To add elements, use [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
var array = ["12", "34", "56"];
array.push("78", "90");
```

To properly remove elements without leaving holes, you need to find their index (you can use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in good browsers, there is a shim on the page for IE) and use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
array.splice(array.indexOf("34"), 1);
array.splice(array.indexOf("56"), 1);
```

Note that if you already know the index and the count, you can just do

```
array.splice(1, 2); //Removes 2 elements starting at index 1
```

Also note that `splice` can also add elements with the same call. Just put them as the last parameters. That means you could do this:

```
var array = ["12", "34", "56"];
array.splice(1, 2, "78", "90"); //array is now ["12", "78", "90"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here seems to be suggesting array based solutions but if all you are ever going to do is add/remove elements and check if they are present or not you can consider using an object as a hash table.

```
var elems = {
   'a': true,
   'b':true
};

//add someone to the list
elems['c'] = true;

//check if someone is in the list
elems.hasOwnProperty('c');

//remove someone from the list
delete elems[c];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding is easy, just use the `push()` method to add an element to the end of the array.

You can remove the first / last item with `shift()` and `pop()` respectively, but if you want to remove a specific element you need to find that element's index using `indexOf()`, then remove it using `splice()`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ for more about the methods.

Answer (score 0):

*After* learning how this can be done using basic ECMAScript array manipulation (as addressed by the other answers),

I would recommend a set of [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). Mainly `map`, `flatmap`, and `filter`.

These are rolled into one in the [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function. However, similar constructs can be found elsewhere, such as [in the ECMAScript 5th Edition Array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) (unfortunately does not have a `flatmap`), or additional libraries like [Functional JavaScript](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/), or manually created (which is a great learning exercise).

Happy coding.