# Comma-Separated string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv

I have a text input that gets updated every time a user selects a new tag (a new creates a new list element) and these list elements are mapped into a comma separated list that is then added to the value a text input.

The value of the text input may look like this,

> PHP, C#, C, C++

A user can click on a tag to remove it from text input, however I cannot see to remove it from the comma seperated list in the input field.

My code looks like this for the tag deletion method.

```
var array = $("#job_tags_input").val().split(",");
```

I though this would give an array of the values in my input but all I get in my console hwen I do my console.log(array) is,

> ["C", " PHP", " Perl", " C#", " "]

If the tag for "C" was deleted how would I remove that from my input field?

MY JS

```
if($("#job_tags").get(0)) {
    $("#job_tags").tagHandler({
        assignedTags: [ 'C', 'Perl', 'PHP' ],
        availableTags: [ 'C', 'C++', 'C#', 'Java', 'Perl', 'PHP', 'Python' ],
        autocomplete: true,
        onAdd: function(tag) { 
            var s = $("#job_tags li").map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get().join(",");
            s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
            console.log(s);
            $('#job_tags_input').val(s);
        },
        onDelete: function(tag) { 
            /*$("#job_tags_input").val( $("#job_tags li").map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get().join(", "));*/
            var array = $("#job_tags_input").val().split(",");
            array = $.grep(array, function(value, i) {
                return ( value.indexOf(tag) == 0 );
            });
            array = array.join(",");
            console.log(array);
            $('#job_tags_input').val(array);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Half this question seems unrelated to the other half.

Comment: If your input has been updated to contain PHP,Perl,C# your output array should not be what you showed. There's some missing code for us to look at here. `"PHP, C#, C, C++".split(',')` outputs `["PHP", " C#", " C", " C++"]`

Comment: That looks like an Array logged to the console.  What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can splice the item first:

```
array.splice(array.indexOf("C"), 1); // remove one item at the position of "C"
```

Then join the elements together and update the textbox:

```
$("#job_tags_input").val(array.join()); // uses "," by default
```

However, you'd be better off splitting on `", "` since the space is part of the delimiter.

Comment: Beware `indexOf` is not supported in all browser.

Comment: And by all browsers he means IE8 and lower. FWIW, I would delete the tag from the input string and always create the array from that. `String.indexOf` is supported by all browsers.

Comment: @pseudosavant how would I go about doing that?

Comment: It depends on how you are choosing to allow users to remove the tags. How are you doing that?

Comment: A user removes a tag by click on the `<li>` that contains that value of the tag, I have updated my question with the javascript I am currently using

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery there are several methods will help. You can split() without the space and use $.trim() to clean whitespace as a space may or may not always exist.

$.grep() can be used to filter an array and return new array.

Comment: here's a fiddle that uses selects to add/remove. Never parses the text field at all and just bounces the values between "assigned" and "available" arrays. http://jsfiddle.net/4pvhS/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to check the `indexOf` removed tag and then `splice` it from the list. Then set the value of the input by joining the spliced list.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/QMdry/3/)

```
var curSelection = $('#job_tags_input').val().split(",");
var elIndex = curSelection.indexOf(t);

if (elIndex >= 0) {
    curSelection.splice(elIndex , 1);
    $('#job_tags_input').val(curSelection.join());
}

$('#job_tags_input').val(curSelection.join());
```

Below function is for Array.indexOf,

```
//Below code is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/144172/297641
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex == null) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
    }
    for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (this[i] === obj)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```