# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead force selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the Bootstrap Typeahead plugin in my app, and here is my code (it's an example).
I'm looking for a way to validate the selection of the user (basically if the input did not match any results -> empty the box on blur). The result must match. I searched everywhere and couldn't find a thing. Your help would be highly appreciated.

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        var states = [];
        var map = {};

        var data = [
            { "stateCode": "CA", "stateName": "California" },
            { "stateCode": "AZ", "stateName": "Arizona" },
            { "stateCode": "NY", "stateName": "New York" },
            { "stateCode": "NV", "stateName": "Nevada" },
            { "stateCode": "OH", "stateName": "Ohio" }
        ];

        $.each(data, function (i, state) {
            map[state.stateName] = state;
            states.push(state.stateName);
        });

        process(states);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743498/bootstrap-typeahead-only-allow-list-values  - instead of the alert just use `.val('')` to empty the input field.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however that doesn't seem to do the trick -> check it http://jsfiddle.net/Q4DBx/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you extract out the data, states and map, you can then use them in the `.blur` function for lookup:

```
 var data = [
            { "stateCode": "CA", "stateName": "California" },
            { "stateCode": "AZ", "stateName": "Arizona" },
            { "stateCode": "NY", "stateName": "New York" },
            { "stateCode": "NV", "stateName": "Nevada" },
            { "stateCode": "OH", "stateName": "Ohio" }
        ];
 var states = [];
 var map = {};

 $.each(data, function (i, state) {
    map[state.stateName] = state;
    states.push(state.stateName);
 });

 $('#search').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        process(states);
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if(states[$(this).val()] == null) {
      $('#search').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from mccannf works, but in my case with `if(parents.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) {` on blur event.