# Bootstrap typeahead function force selection

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I know this question is asked so many times but the same is not working on my side. I want to force user to select result in typeahead, if he do not select on blur empty input box.

I used type like on blur, typeahead:selected. On blur is working but I am not getting selected data and typeahead:selected is not working at all

Please see this link for earlier answer [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827576/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-force-selection), [link2](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/163) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128501/twitters-typeahead-example-dynamic-query)

Below is my code with onblur

```
var newData = [];
$('.search').each(function() {
  var idName = this.id;
  var $this = $(this);
   $this.typeahead({
   source:function(query,process){
    if( typeof searching != "undefined") {
     clearTimeout(searching);
     process([]);
 }
   searching = setTimeout(function() {
      return $.getJSON(
     "batchEnable.jsp?autosearch="+idName,
      { q:query },
       function(data){
       $.each(data, function(){
       newData.push(this.name);
  });
 // only search if stop typing for 300ms aka fast typers
   return process(newData);
      });
   }, 300); // 300 ms
 },
}).blur(function(){
  if(newData[$(this).val()] == null) { 
  // I am always getting this null (newData[$(this).val()]), 
  //if even if I select typeahead result data
  $('#'+idName+'').val('');
   newData = [];
  }
 });
});
```

Code with on selected with is not getting called on selection of typeahead data

```
.on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
    console.log(datum);  // datum will contain the value that was autocompleted
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept hidden value in the field with flag 0 and 1. If he select results from typeahead then updater function is getting called and and I set the flag value to 1 and onblur if flag is not equal to one then I will empty input text box onblur. And one more thing whenever user type any thing I am clearing the flag value.

Below is the code for working for the same.

```
$('.search').each(function() {
  var idName = this.id;
  var $this = $(this);
  var map = {};      
  $this.typeahead({
    source:function(query,process){
     if( typeof searching != "undefined") {
       clearTimeout(searching);
       process([]);
     }
     searching = setTimeout(function() {
     return $.getJSON(
     "batchEnable.jsp?autosearch="+idName,
     { q:query },
     function(data){
     var regions = [];
     $("#"+idName+"_").val("");

      $.each(data, function(){
        map[this.name] = this.id;                                   
        regions.push(this.name);
      });  

      // only search if stop typing for 300ms aka fast typers
      process(regions);
    });
  }, 300); // 300 ms
 },
 updater: function (item) {
 selectedState = map[item];

 // this will set id in input hidden as per the idname_
  $("#"+idName+"_").val(selectedState);
  return item;
 }
}).blur(function(){

 // onblur check if user has selected value in typeahead drop down if he has not     selected then hidden value will be blank and then empty input text also
  var hiddenValue = $("#"+idName+"_").val();              
  if(hiddenValue == null || hiddenValue == ""){
    $("#"+idName).val("");      
  }
 });
});
```