# How to restrict user to select value from auto populated list only in jQuery? (i.e. user should not be able to enter new entry)

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm using Bootstrap's typeahed plugin to achieve the auto populate functionality on a text field. At the back end the I'm getting the necessary matching data elements through AJAX, PHP and MySQL.

Everything is working fine for me. But there is one issue: I don't want user to accept data other than the data items appeared in auto populated list. In other words, I want to restrict user to select data element from the auto populated list only. He/she shouldn't be able to enter data other than the entries present in auto populated data item list.

The **typeahead.js** has already been included. I'm using **jquery-1.9.1.min.js**

My HTML and jQuery code is as follows:

```
<form action="xyz.php" id="xyz" name ="xyz" method="post">

<input type="text" class="form-control demo" size="20" autocomplete="on" id="id" name="id" value="">
</form> 

$('.demo').keyup(function() {
  $(".demo").typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
      var textVal   = $(".demo").val();


      $.ajax({
        url: 'xyz.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'op=get_data',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          process(data);
        //console.log(textVal);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If you want any further information please do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Typeahead Only Allow List Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743498/bootstrap-typeahead-only-allow-list-values)

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution can be to watch the user input, and auto-correct its entries.

If you have FRANCE in your list, and the user begin to enter 'fr', you could do nothing, but if you have no one item beginning by 'fr', you can either color in red his entry, or auto-correct, erasing the impossible value.

For example, if you have FINLAND in the list, you just remove only the 'r'.

This way, the user understand instantly that any item not in the list is avoided.