# typehead disallow free text entry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typehead

I am using bootstrap typeahead in my textbox to bind the list of users through Ajax call 
here is my code

```
$("#userMapping_User").typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get($_GetUsers_ByLoggedInUser, { term: query }, function (result) {

            var resultList = [];
            $.map(result, function (item, id) {
                if (item && (item.first_name || item.last_name)) {
                    var displayName = item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name;
                    var user = { id: item.UserId, name: displayName ? displayName.trim() + ' - ' + item.email : '' };
                    resultList.push(user);
                }
            });
            return process(resultList);
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    autoSelect: true,
    afterSelect: function (e) {
        $("#userMapping_SelectedUserId").val(e.id);
        $("#userMapping_User").removeClass('form-error');
        $(".error-block").remove();
    }
});
```

But the problem is  that I want to disable the free text entry so the user cannot able to enter invalid value only those value is inserted which are available in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this thing with the below code.

```
var myData = [...]; // This array will contain all your possible data for the typeahead

$("#my-type-ahead").typeahead({source : myData})
                   .blur(validateSelection);

function validateSelection() {
    if(source.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) 
        alert('Error : element not in list!');
}
```

This was the answer given by @samuel in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743498/bootstrap-typeahead-only-allow-list-values). But I suppose you can do better by using callback function and prevent value being entered. Its your choice.

Cheers..!!