# How to check that is list of objects or list of strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does anybody know how to check that a list contain objects or strings?

Comment: loop on the elements and use typeof.

Comment: @dievardump, I have tired with looping and checking the item whether that is 'object' or 'string'. But I want to check without looping through the list.

Comment: For objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: @NkS if you are sure the list will always contain the same type, so you can juste typeof the first element in the list. Else you will have to iterate. But you can have a clever iteration. One which will stop as soon as there is more than one type (and return something like `'mixed'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript all arrays are untyped, meaning: nothing will take care of what is in it, if you don't do it yourself.

Since array is a composite structure addressed by an integer value, you can check every address for the exact type stored inside. If this is an array created by someone else.
However, what is your array type if you find objects, strings and int's in it?

Other options:

- create your own structure where you specify type on its creation and throw error in `add(item)` method if the items type is violated
- create your own structure where in `add(item)` you take care of the type and write it in some property of that structure

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the array and use the condition `typeof variable === "string"` and `typeof variable === "object"` to find out.

Comment: avoid == and use === for comparison