# Need to recovered a value in an array from the ID

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function f() {
    var FileSize = "250";
    var Ana = new Array;
    Ana["231.78"] = "2.14";
    Ana["234.95"] = "2.11";
    Ana["238.12"] = "2.08";
    Ana["241.30"] = "2.05";
    Ana["244.47"] = "2.02";
    Ana["250.82"] = "1.97";
    Ana["254.00"] = "1.95";
}
f();
```

I don't know how to write my request.
I have a value (250) and need to test the Array until the ID of my Array is less than my "FileSize". In my example, the result should be 1.97.

Comment: Note that an array can't have fractional indexes. What you actually have is a zero-length array object with 7 custom properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to find an item in a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: How is the result `1.97`?  Isn't `250.82 > 250`?

Answer (score 0):

Using simple arrays for your problem might not be the best representation. You could an array of couples :

```
var Ana = [
   [231.78, 2.14],
   ...
   [254.00, 1.95]
];
```

This way, you can easily sort your `Ana` array by ascending order (ascending order regarding the first element of each couple). And you can iterate through your `Ana` array until you reach your condition, with a simple `while` or `for` loop. If you keep `Ana` sorted, recovering the value is easy and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the file size as the key, store the whole information as an object in the array:

```
var f = function(fileSize){

var ana = [];
ana.push({fileSize: 231.78, randomThing: 2.14});
ana.push({fileSize: 234.95, randomThing: 2.11});
ana.push({fileSize: 234.95, randomThing: 2.08});
ana.push({fileSize: 241.30, randomThing: 2.05});
ana.push({fileSize: 244.47, randomThing: 2.02});
ana.push({fileSize: 250.82, randomThing: 1.97});
ana.push({fileSize: 254.00, randomThing: 1.95});

for(var i=0; i < ana.length; i++){
    if (ana[i].fileSize > fileSize){
        return ana[i].randomThing;
    }
}

return null; //or something more appropriate, this happens when there is no item greater than fileSize  
}
```