# Why doesn't my code work for finding if a value exists in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find if a value exists or not in an array and then add it to a third array. I am using JavaScript.

Here are my declarations:

```
var testArray1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var testArray2 = [];
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
var x = testArray1.length;
var y = 0;

do {
    if(typeof testArray1[y] == 'a') {
    console.value += "A doesn't exist.";
    }
    else {
    console.value += "A does exist."
    }
    y++;
while (y < x);
```

For some reason (even if I enter in `(anything greater than 0)` instead of `x` it always says `A does exist.` Could anyone point me out where my code is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `typeof` **never** returns `'a'`. What do you think `typeof` does? How/why do you conclude from the equality to `"a"` that the value does exist?

Comment: See [Best way to find an item in a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/143847/218196) for a solution to test existence of an element in an array.

Comment: Notice that your solution will not work for empty arrays. Don't use a `do-while`-loop here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this way simpler for yourself.

`testArray1.indexOf('a')` will return the index of that letter in the array. If it's not in the array it will return -1

```
if(testArray1.indexOf('a') != -1){
     // it is in the array
}else{
     // it's not in the array
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and, _quite frankly_, easy answer! That simplifies my code quite a bit!

Comment: @TheMan: For future questions, I recommend to ask *exactly* what you want. You currently ask for an explanation why your code does not work, not how to correctly test for existence (which would be a duplicate anyway).

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't my code work for finding if a value exists in an array in JavaScript?

Because [`typeof x` returns the **type** of the value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (according to the specification). `typeof testArray1[y]` will always return `"string"` for every value in your array, because every value is a string. It will never return `'a'`.

Have a look at [Best way to find if an item is in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/143847/218196) and [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/218196) to learn how to test for existence of a value in an array.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I would approach solving the problem like this.

```
var _testArray1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var _testArray2 = [];

for (var _i = 0; _i < _testArray1.length; _i++) {
    if (_testArray1[_i] === "a") {
        _testArray2.push(_testArray1[_i]);
    }
    // other logic;
};
```

In this way, you keep your iteration count variable within its own scope, as well as append the found array result to the already declared variable.