# Use underscore to return true or false with findWhere

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Let's say I have the following data:

```
var data = {
    activeUser: { id: 3, name: 'Joe', something: 'else' },
    location: {
        users: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
    }
};
```

I want to return a boolean whether or not the `activeUser` can be found in the `data.location.users` array. Note that the objects in the `location.users` array will NOT have the same keys as the `activeUser` object.

Is there a normal underscore way to do this? I have the following.

```
var userExists = (_.findWhere(data.location.users, {id: data.activeUser.id})) ? true : false;
```

I'm using the `findWhere` method to either return an object or null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-if-an-item-is-in-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One alternative option would be to use the [`._some()` method](http://underscorejs.org/#some). It will return a boolean based on whether anything was found:

```
var userExists = _.some(data.location.users, function (user) {
  return user.id === data.activeUser.id;
});
```