# How do I use an if statement to search an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have this challenge which in my head seems easy enough, but I can't seem to get my function right.

The challenge is as follows:

Create a function that determines if a given name is amongst the names.

So here is my array and function -

```
 var family = ["Steve", "John", "Dani", "Bob"];

 function searchName(f){
   for (i=0; i<family.length; i++){
     if ((family.lastIndexOf(f) != family[i]))
       {family[i]}
   }
 }

 searchName("Moe");
```

Now all this returns is undefined. Which is better than errors I suppose. What I want it to do is when I pass through a name that is not in the array to have it return a false statement, and if a name that is in the array, true. I also know that I need to throw in `.toUpperCase` and `.toLowerCase` in there as well to account for the case sensitivity. My assumption is that rather than just an if statement, I need an if/else if/ else.

Comment: I suggest you look over the methods available on arrays. You will find `indexOf` which already does what you want. It will return -1 if there's no match, or an index greater than or equal to zero if there is. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array.

Comment: `alert(["Steve", "John", "Dani", "Bob"].includes("Moe"))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/143863/3399676

Comment: `alert(/\bMoe\b/.test(["Steve", "John", "Dani", "Bob"]))`

Comment: `alert(["Steve", "John", "Dani", "Bob"].some(/./.test, /\bMoe\b/))`

Comment: Your function returns undefined because you have no `return` statement. Using a for loop to test each item in the array is one way to do it, but if you do that you don't want `lastIndexOf()`, you want something like `if (f === family[i]) { return true; }` and then put a `return false;` after the loop. You don't need an else block.

Comment: @dandavis could you please explain that line of code?

        alert(["Steve", "John", "Dani", "Bob"].some(/./.test, /\bMoe\b/))

Comment: some returns true/false based on any array element causing the callback to return true-ish. the callback function i use tests the element against the RegExp, and if it matches, the iteration is stopped and true is returned.