# What's difference between find() and indexOf() methods for array

Tags: javascript

[Best way to find if an item is in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-if-an-item-is-in-a-javascript-array)

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
array.indexOf(2);     // 0
array.indexOf(7);     // -1


let found = array.find(x => x === 5 );
console.log(found); //5

found = array.find(x => x === 51 );
console.log(found); //undefined
```

What method use to detect value in array ?

`array.indexOf(val) !== -1` or

```
typeof array.find(x => x === val ) !== 'undefined';
```

Comment: `find` returns a **value**, `indexOf` returns **`index`** in the array

Comment: I prefer to use `~array.indexOf(5)` instead of `array.indexOf(5) !== -1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference comes when you have array of objects.

#### Sample

```js
var d = [
  {a:1, b: "test"},
  {a:2, b: "test"},
  {a:3, b: "test"},
  {a:4, b: "test"},
  {a:5, b: "test"},
];
  
var r = d.find(x=> x.a===5);
console.log(r)
```

In such case, `.indexOf` will not be feasible.

Also, `array.find` will return matched element but `indexOf` will return the index of matched element.

Also, if the objective is to check if value exists in array, you can even look into `Array.some`

#### Sample

```js
var d = [
  {a:1, b: "test"},
  {a:2, b: "test"},
  {a:3, b: "test"},
  {a:4, b: "test"},
  {a:5, b: "test"},
];
  
var r = d.some(x=> x.a===5);
console.log(r)
```

#### References

- [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the item itself and [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) the index of the item.

With `Array#find`, you have to check for `undefined`, which is misleading if the value you are looking for is `undefined`. In this case, I suggest to use `Array#indexOf`, where you can check if the value is not in the array, because of the return value of `-1` which is no valid index.

If you works on a system without ES6, you have to use `Array#indexOf`.

In your case, to get just a confirmation if the value is in the array, you may use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (ES6), which returns a boolen value.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the official MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf),

**The `find()` method** returns **a value** in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Whereas,

**The `indexOf()` method** returns **the first index** at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

In conclusion, each method is intended for its own dedicated use.