# Updating child values in DOM

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuex

I use **vuejs** for the app and **firebase** for the database services.

The database structure looks as below:
[image]

The initial state of the the app is as follows:

```
const state :{
    newStatus: [],
    statuses: [],
    initialStatusFetched: false
}
```

When the app is created the fullowing events are triggered in the `created()` lifecycle hook which fetch the statuses from the firebase and add it to the arrays in the initial state mentioned above:

```
created(){
    //fetches initial status and adds it to statuses[ ]
    function fetchStatus() {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref(); 
        ref.child("allstatuses").once('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
                let childKey = childSnap.ke;
                let childData = childSnap.val();
                let statusData = {
                    key: childKey,
                    statusVal : childData
                }
                state.statuses.unshift(statusData);
                state.loader = false;
                state.initialStatusFetched = true;
            });
        });
    };

    //fetches newly added status and adds it to newStatus[ ]
    function statusAdded() {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref(); 
        ref.child("allstatuses").on('child_added', function(status) {
            if(state.initialStatusFetched){
                let statusData = {
                    key: status.key,
                    statusVal: status.val()
                }
                state.newStatus.push(statusData);
            }
        });
    };

}
```

Now using the arrays which gets filled with the events triggered above I populate the page with statuses using the following template:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div>    
          <!--statuses-->
      <div v-for="status in statuses" class="media my-media"> 
          // ommitted all the un-important part
          <div class="media-body">

              <button @click="addlike(status.key, userStatus.loggedIn)" class="btn my-btn">Like</button>
            //displaying number of likes
              <span style="margin-right:20px">{{ status.statusVal.likes }}</span>
              <button @click="addDislike(status.key, userStatus.loggedIn)" class="btn my-btn">Disike</button>
            //displaying number of dislikes
              <span>{{ status.statusVal.dislikes }}</span> 

          </div>          
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>    
</template>
```

**so now the problem i am facing is**

```
function updateLikes() {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref(); 
        ref.child("allstatuses/" + statuskey + "/likes").on('value', (snapshot) => {
            // hiw can I fetch the value os statusKey so i can use it above
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
    };
```

- how can I get the value of **statusKey** so I can use it to refer to the node and update the value of likes using the above code?
- how do i know which status's likes got updated in the database and where that particular status is in the statuses[ ] , since statuses [ ] gets on added by new statuses?

Comment: I do not know if I got it right. You want to change the values "on screen" when you have any changes in the database. Would it be this?

Comment: @LucasTorres yup , you got it right,, thats what i want

Comment: Try 'watch' with 'deep: true' https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

Comment: Can you post the HTML elements of "likes" div?

Comment: @LucasTorres yup i will in a moment

Comment: Instead of describing the code, edit your question to include a [single, minimal, complete snippet of code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yup working on formatting my code so i can display it......

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sir I have added the relevant code that i used...have a look

Comment: That's a lot of code. But it seems that in both your `value` and your `child_added` listener, you know what `status` you're processing. What is the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen since the posts are added to the array how do i know which post's likes or dislikes changed so i can update them

Comment: Are you asking [how to find an item in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-if-an-item-is-in-a-javascript-array)? Or [how to listen for updates to child nodes in the Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i think my question is too confusing. i will re-format the question and post you the link of the question again.

Comment: If *this* question is too confusing, edit *this* question to make it clearer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i will let you once i have edited the question. Thank u !

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sir i have edited my question completly above and tried my best to ellaborate it please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For q1: you'll need to keep the key of each item in the HTML and then pass that into `updateLikes()` when the user clicks on it. Probably [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions):

```
function updateLikes(statuskey) {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref(); 
    ref.child("allstatuses/" + statuskey + "/likes")
       .transaction(function(currentValue) {
         return (currentValue || 0) + 2
       });
```

For q2: listen for the `child_changed` event, which fires when the data of a child changes. Given that you already kept the key for each item in the answer for q1, you can now look up the element in the HTML that needs to be updated:

```
    ref.child("allstatuses").on('child_changed', function(status) {
        var statusElm = document.getElementById(status.key);
        ... update the HTML for the new status
    });
```

Comment: Using transaction ti write to the database was working gud,,, the 2nd part confused me.... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, a dont know vue.js, but in pure Javascript It would be something like this:

```
<div id="likes"></div>
```

Inside your `ref.on('value', function(snap){})`You will map until you reach the `child` "likes"  and put the value in the variable `value` for example and:

```
let likes = document.getElementById('likes');
likes.innerHTML(value);
```

Comment: Yup that I know , since the posts are in array how to know which likes is to be updated as i dont know where the post would be in the array at a point of time