# What is the difference between .find() and .includes() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a method called addTrack with the following functionality:

- Accepts a track argument
- Use the track’s id property to check if the
  current song is in the playlistTracks state
- If the id is new, add the song to the end of the playlist.
- Set the new state of the playlist.

What would be the difference if I use the code #1 instead of code #2?

PlaylistTracks is defined in the constructor as following:

```
playlistTracks: [{ name: 'name1', artist: 'artist1', album: 'album1', id: 1 },
        { name: 'name2', artist: 'artist2', album: 'album2', id: 2 },
      ]
```

**Code #1**

```
addTrack(track){
if (this.state.playlistTracks.includes(this.props.track.id)) {return;}
else {this.state.playlistTracks.push(track);
  this.setState({playlistTracks:this.state.playlistTracks});
}
```

}

**Code #2**

```
addTrack(track) {
if (this.state.playlistTracks.find(savedTrack => savedTrack.id===track.id) {return;}
else {return this.state.playlistTracks.push(track);}
this.setState(playlistTracks:this.state.playlistTracks)}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`array.includes` will just return true or false if the value is there or not

`array.find` will find the specific item in the array for you

e.g.

```
[1,2,3].includes(1) // returns true
[1,2,3].includes(4) // returns false

[1,2,3].find(i => i === 1) // returns 1
[1,2,3].find(i => i === 5) // returns undefined
```

Comment: Got it! Wouldn't the way the code #1 is written still bring a solution for the explained purpose? It checks if it's a new id, if so the new track is added to the list of playlistTracks.

Comment: use `includes` if you just want to know "if something is in the array". if you want to actually find a specific track for whatever reason, use find. I would use `includes` in your case. as you just want to know if it exists in the playlist right?

Comment: Yes, and if it is not in the playlist, then add it to playlistTracks.

Comment: exactly! nice one. if that helps you, please accept the answer when you can :). if you get stuck on anything don't hesitate to reach out